# Tab-completion in order to access org-roam ecosystem

Tags: org-mode, completion, org-roam

I'm looking to access an .org note at a specific heading, in such a way that tab completion is available. Is there any such thing? usage example: `<command> microeconomics <tab-completed-heading>`, or `<command> <tab-completed-university-class-name> introduction`